# Infinte loop (strstr)

Tags: c, linked-list

I have an infinite loop inside this method because of the strstr function. Is it because I'm matching a struct type to a char type?

```
car* find(char* type){

    car* stringCurr = list_head();
    while(stringCurr != NULL){
        if(strstr(stringCurr->info, type)){  //This line
           return stringCurr;
        }
    }
  return NULL;
}
```

Struct:

```
typedef struct Machine{

  char info[128];
  struct Machine* next;

}car;
```

**EDIT:**

The goal is to make a search function and return NULL if the object is found in the list

Comment: The infinite loop is coming because the headString doesn't contain string type and you are not incrementing stringCurr.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Understood, but this is a search function so what I need to increment exactly?

Comment: I am assuming that your list_head() function returns the head of the linkedlist. Now the value of your stringCurr is pointing to the head of the linked list, and since the if statement is not true, we won't return anything and the while loop will continue. Since we are not changing the value of stringCurr, the while loop will never end.

Comment: What does list_head() do ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Yes list_head() is pointing to the head of the list. I did this method in a way that if the object is not found it will add it to the list else it will return NULL(meaning that the object is already in the list). Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Can you please post how a type `car` looks like  in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed incrementing the stringCurr. You need to do something similar to `stringCurr = stringCurr->next` in the while loop.

```
car* find(char* type){

    car* stringCurr = list_head();
    while(stringCurr != NULL){
        if(strstr(stringCurr->info, type)){  //This line
           return stringCurr;
        }
       stringCurr = stringCurr -> next;
    }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the error still persists.

Comment: @DontStopLearn The above solution, I posted is not stopping the infinite loop ?

Comment: Yes, it did work now! Thanks, my mistake was that I've put the phrase in the if statement...

Comment: Glad to know that it helped :)